# How can I create winding paths in leaflet like in google maps?

Tags: leaflet

I'm fairly new to Leaflet. I want to create winding paths inside polygon in leaflet as I give below example link. How can I do that?

e.g. [Google Maps API Winding path within polygon with rotate/grow/shrink/order options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42144047/google-maps-api-winding-path-within-polygon-with-rotate-grow-shrink-order-option/)

and

for example  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFroR.png

Comment: First of all, read through https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#edit-geometries .

Comment: Thanks for the link. After struggling for a while, I was able to do what I wanted.